# How to get Scrapy Response in Scrapy Shell

Tags: python, python-2.7, ipython, scrapy

I'm new to the Scrapy project and have read many tutorials. They all seem to assume that you know how to parse the response object right away, and that you can immediately invoke the response callback (e.g. `scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)`). But in reality, I need to work through the CSS selectors using trial-and-error.

How do I get the Scrapy response object back so that I can manipulate it interactively?

The response of `scrapy.Request(url=url)` seems to be something I can't work with (see screenshot) - nothing to parse the HTML with - no `.css` method for instance. 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the shell, use `fetch(request)`

- `fetch(url[, redirect=True])` - fetch a new response from the given URL and update all related objects accordingly. You can optionaly ask for HTTP 3xx redirections to not be followed by passing redirect=False
- `fetch(request)` - fetch a new response from the given request and update all related objects accordingly.

Comment: Thanks! And based on your update to my question, I also found this, which was very helpful - https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html

Answer (score -1):

scrapy works asynchronously, and the `callback` methods on the requests are to determine which "method" will receive the `response` object in this case.

so if you've really follow many tutorials, you'll have something like:

```
def parse(self, response):
    ...

    yield Request(url='myurl', callback=self.some_other_method)

def some_other_method(self, response):
    ...
    # play with the response object of the request done to `myurl`
```

that way, you get the responses on a sequential manner.